# Slurm not filtering sacct results by date

Tags: ubuntu, resource-management, slurm

We're using Slurm as a resource manager on our Beowulf cluster, so I installed Slurm on my workstation to test out my scripts before I submit them to the cluster.

When I try to list old jobs on my workstation, `sacct` won't filter them by date.

```
$ sacct -o jobid,state,start,end -S 2017-06-11T00:00
       JobID      State               Start                 End 
------------ ---------- ------------------- ------------------- 
2                FAILED 2017-04-07T13:39:43 2017-04-07T13:39:45 
3             CANCELLED 2017-04-07T13:39:45 2017-04-07T13:39:45 
4                FAILED 2017-04-07T13:44:53 2017-04-07T13:44:54 
5             CANCELLED 2017-04-07T13:44:54 2017-04-07T13:44:54 
6                FAILED 2017-04-07T13:51:01 2017-04-07T13:51:02 
7             CANCELLED 2017-04-07T13:51:02 2017-04-07T13:51:02 
8                FAILED 2017-04-07T14:05:30 2017-04-07T14:05:32 
9             CANCELLED 2017-04-07T14:05:32 2017-04-07T14:05:32 
.
.
.
27097         COMPLETED 2017-05-24T09:46:26 2017-05-24T09:46:30 
27098         COMPLETED 2017-05-24T09:46:26 2017-05-24T09:46:30 
27099         COMPLETED 2017-05-24T09:46:26 2017-05-24T09:46:29 
27100         COMPLETED 2017-05-24T09:46:26 2017-05-24T09:46:28 
27101         COMPLETED 2017-05-24T09:46:26 2017-05-24T09:46:29 
27095         COMPLETED 2017-05-24T09:46:29 2017-05-24T09:46:32 
27102         COMPLETED 2017-05-24T09:46:32 2017-05-24T09:46:39 
27103         COMPLETED 2017-05-24T09:46:40 2017-05-24T09:46:44 
27104         COMPLETED 2017-05-24T09:46:40 2017-05-24T09:46:42 
27105         COMPLETED 2017-06-12T13:52:48 2017-06-12T13:52:49
```

How can I tell `sacct` to just display the entries after 2017-06-11?

Comment: I am inclined to believe this is a bug. What versions of Slurm are you using?

Comment: I'm using slurm 15.08.7 on Ubuntu 16.04, @LeviMorrison.